# Provisioning profile issue in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile

My Provisioning profile is going to expire in two days,so build in the device will not work after that. is there any method to update the old profile and to make work build as usual.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create update you provision profile from http:developer.apple.com. if you have apple developer account.

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Provisioning-Profile-for-iPhone

Comment: Thank's Ashrith..... after updating the profile will the old build in the device works normal or else not

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended way but if its not currently possible to refresh/update your profile from apple's developer center for some reason, try changing your date few days back. This should temporarily work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer **NO**. If you have provided a build to lets say a client and it uses a provisioning profile that expires in two days then it will expire. You will need to provide a new build to your clients device with a new provisioning profile in it. The apps are set to use a certain provisioning profile when you do your build so trying to magically update that on a device will make the app not work on the uses device.